# Outlook Addin - How can I set “High Importance” on email sent using C# in VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to know how do I set the headers of email on click on checkboxes. I have created required checkboxes in FormRegion.

Example: 
I have checkbox named HighImportance, on click of that I want to change the email header.
I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.OutlookItem.Importance = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast the item as a MailItem, then set its importance.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Outlook.MailItem myMailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)this.OutlookItem;
  myMailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `Outlook.MailItem`. What I'm guessing you're looking for is the `Importance` property.

More info on the MailItem object here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_properties(v=office.14).aspx

The values to which you can set the Importance property are listed here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olimportance(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Yes, but how do I set it, that is the Question Mark!

Comment: You need to set the value to a value out of the OlImportance enumeration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olimportance(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the following property:

> PR_IMPORTANCE
> Identifier:
>
> 0x0017
>
> Data type:
>
> PT_LONG
> Area:
>
> General messaging

Accepted values:

> IMPORTANCE_LOW
>
> IMPORTANCE_HIGH
>
> IMPORTANCE_NORMAL

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815346(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815346%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

**Here you have a code sample I did some time ago:**

Set the property:

```
private string HighPrioritySchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0017";


//Being item an Oulook Item:

  item = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)folder.Items[i];   
  item.UserProperties.Add(HighPrioritySchema,
                             Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, true,
                             Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText);
  item.UserProperties[HighPrioritySchema].Value = "IMPORTANCE_HIGH";    
  item.Save();
```

**`//To get the property that has been previously set:`**

```
 Outlook.PropertyAccessor pacc = item.PropertyAccessor;
 pacc.GetProperties(HighPrioritySchema);
```

Comment: OutlookItem item = new OutLooItem(); gives error as OutLookItem is not a class! what to do?

Comment: Why would you take that complex way if you can just set `mailItem.Importance`?

Comment: @cremor he tried using  this.OutlookItem.Importance = 2; and it did not work.